# Is there any way to launch an "empty" JVM instance without giving it a Main class to run?

Tags: java, jvm, execution

For example, just to test that a given set of VM parameters "work" and are valid.

I could always make a class with an empty main method or something, but then I have to worry about the classpath and all that jazz, which it'd be nice to avoid.

Comment: What's the point of starting a JVM and not giving it a program to execute?

Comment: You might try giving `-version` along with the other parameters that you want to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that appears to be what I'm after!

Comment: As for what the point is, fair question.

In my case, I'm attempting to search for the largest value for max memory (-Xmx) that I can successfully launch a JVM with. We have a user interface that allows the user to specify a max memory, but users can potentially specify too much.

The hard limit seems a bit more tricky to calculate than simply checking the system's memory, so I thought I'd give this approach a go and see how it works out.

Comment: @fragorl Why not allow the user to specify as much as they want? It's their computer ;)

Comment: We frequently encounter users setting their max memory equal to their system's entire physical memory, or nearly that amount, despite warnings (we don't let them set an amount larger, for obvious reasons). The message given when the JVM fails to allocate a heap of a certain size, and hence fails to start, is often confusing to users, and it would be nice to circumvent it altogether by treating their specified amount as a maximum, but a maximum that could potentially be too large.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify a long classpath, just make an empty java program in whatever directory you're starting the VM from in terminal. You can do that from within the terminal with vi.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute `java -version` and add any set of VM parameters that you like. This will parse the parameters and instantiate a VM instance.

For example: `java -version -Xmn64m`.

You can also do `java -Xmn64m abc` where `abc` is a random string. This will report that it could not find the main class "abc" but it will still first parse the Java parameters and instantiate a VM instance. It actually is supposed to execute slightly more initialization tasks than the `java -version` does so it is good for testing.